# How to achieve semaphore concept in Java Multithreading? Producer Consumer

Tags: java, objective-c, multithreading, semaphore

I've two threads Producer and Consumer. In objective-c language I've used semaphores to block and release thread Consumer.

**Note:** This is related to Producer-Consumer Problem But not fully. Here Producer will not wait for consumer to consume. But consumer will wait till Producer produces. Here Consumer is not continuously reading. He's reading Only when Producer tells him to read. And reads only some data. **And here its not about shared memory kinda**.

```
Thread Consumer{
   while(true) {
       //Consumer is waiting
       dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphoreVariable, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
       //Copies the data and then goes to wait. 
   }
}

Thread Producer{
  while(true){
     //write to buffer
     //Continuously writes to buffer. No Waiting.
     //After writing Some Blocks asks consumer to consume
     dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaPhoreBlock);
  }
}
```

Like this the semaphore is used to continuously block and release Consumer Thread.

How to achieve this kind of mechanism in JAVA? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are after http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've read that before. Here Consumer is not continuously reading. He's reading Only when Producer tells him to read.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this coordination problem with a "barrier".

The consumer won't read continuously. It only reads a batch of work when the producer notifies him to do so (by reseting the barrier).

I added some waiting for the producer too (so the queue won't overflow if the consumer is too slow), but the producer will only wait if after producing a batch of work, there is no consumer ready to consume it.

see below:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class BarrierExample {

    public static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BarrierExample barrierExample = new BarrierExample();
        barrierExample.doTheWork();
    }

    private void doTheWork() throws InterruptedException {


        Queue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.submit(new Producer(BATCH_SIZE, queue, barrier));
        executorService.submit(new Consumer(BATCH_SIZE, queue, barrier));


        Thread.sleep(4000);

        System.out.println("main program:  trying to shutdown executor service");
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

class Producer implements Callable<Void> {
    private final int batchSize;
    private Queue queue;
    private CyclicBarrier barrier;

    private Random random = new Random();


    public Producer(int batchSize, Queue queue, CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() {
        while (true) {
            IntStream.range(1, batchSize).forEach(i -> queue.add(String.valueOf(random.ints(1, 10).findFirst().getAsInt())));
            System.out.println("producer: batch size was added to queue.");

            while (barrier.getNumberWaiting() < 1) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("producer: nobody is waiting on barrier. going to sleep now");
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("producer: consumer was waiting on barrier. reseting the barrier now");
            barrier.reset();

            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("producer is ending now!");
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Consumer implements Callable<Void> {
    private final int batchSize;
    private Queue queue;
    private CyclicBarrier barrier;


    public Consumer(int batchSize, Queue queue, CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() {
        while (true) {
            boolean barrierIsBroken = false;
            try {
                System.out.println("consumer: waiting on barrier");
                barrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                System.out.println("consumer: barrier is broken!!");
                barrierIsBroken = true;
            }

            if (barrierIsBroken) {
                System.out.println("consumer: consuming batch");
                IntStream.range(1, batchSize).forEach(i -> System.out.println(queue.remove()));
                System.out.println("consumer: queue size:" + queue.size());
            }
            try {
                System.out.println("consumer: going to sleep");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("consumer is ending now!");
                break;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java solution is: don't go for "low level" concepts such a using/implemeenting semaphores.

Instead, use one of the many *abstractions* that the Java platform is offering, for example the [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/linkedblockingqueue.html).

It is pretty simple: when you got two threads, one thread pushes content into the queue; and the the other *reader* thread uses the `take()` method in order to fetch content.

Where: `take()` blocks! Therefore you don't need to worry at all about sending signals "manually". One thread writes, the reader sits and waits until content becomes available. Meaning: you do **not** need to tell the reader explicitly "start reading" - that happens **implicitly**, under the covers.

In that sense: the **real** answer is to **study** the offerings that Java has to make, instead of trying to build abstractions yourself. A good starting point are the Oracle [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) on concurrency. Don't assume that your solution from language A must "work" the same way in another language. In Java, the writer does **not need** to signal the reader when using a BlockingQueue. So don't make your life more complicated by enforcing a concept that comes from **another** language!